Did Napoleon ever shoot a bookseller?
In The Oxford Book of Literary Anecdotes (1975) there is a story about Thomas Campbell (1777-1844) that runs as follows:

At a literary dinner Campbell asked leave to propose a toast, and gave
the health of Napoleon Bonaparte. The war was at its height, and the very mention of Napoleon's name, except in conjunction with some uncomplimentary epithet, was in most circles regarded as an outrage.
A storm of groans broke out, and Campbell with difficulty could get a few sentences heard. 'Gentlemen,' he said, 'you must not mistake me. I admit that the French Emperor is a tyrant. I admit that he is a monster. I admit that he is the sworn foe of our nation, and, if you will, of the whole human race. But, gentlemen, we must be just to our great enemy. We must not forget that he once shot a bookseller.' The guests, of whom two out of every three lived by their pens, burst into a roar of laughter, and Campbell sat down in triumph.

This is anecdote #245. I found it very funny, but — who is the bookseller who Napoleon supposedly shot?

This is presumably the Nuremberg bookseller Johann Philipp Palm. Napoleon did not shoot him personally, but he was shot on Napoleon's orders on the charge of distributing anti-Bonapartist pamphlets, following the Austrian defeat at Austerlitz.
There is an excellent description of the events at this military history website:

Johann Philipp Palm (b., 17 November 1768 at Schorndorfd., 26 August
1806 at Braunau-am-Inn), an obscure bookseller from Nuremberg, was
executed in the early afternoon of 26 August 1806. He was shot by a
French firing squad in a field outside of the town of Braunau, an
Austrian town garrisoned by the French. A single pistol shot to the
head finished him off. Palm had been arrested 12 days earlier and
charged with publishing and distributing libelous pamphlets about
France and Napoleon. A military court had tried Palm on 25 August 1806
and found him guilty.

The website notes how the execution was turned into a propaganda tool:

Napoleon's opponents used Palm's execution to inflame public opinion.
A deluge of cartoons and pamphlets were directed against the French
and Napoleon. It is usually reported that execution particularly
outraged the Prussian king, helping to convince him to declare war on
France. However it was the formation of the Confederacy and especially
the news, which was received by the Prussian King on 6 August 1806,
that France had offered Hanover to England in a bid for peace that
were the real causes of the war. Orders had been given on 9 August to
mobilize the Prussian army. The execution of Palm served as a
convenient moral lever to use against Napoleon's France. By the
beginning of September Napoleon was already preparing for war.


Poor Braunau, peaceful little border town, now forever remembered for this terrible incident.

@SebastianKoppehel - Is that a joke based on the fact that Adolf Hitler was born there?

Thanks!
Poor old Palm — probably the only reason he is remembered ...
